Getting valid/original Openbox configuration raw .xml files
Making a package verification of all my Ubuntu 22.04.5 system files, I got this result:
??5?????? c /etc/xdg/openbox/menu.xml
??5?????? c /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml
??5?????? c /etc/sudoers

I know I can't fix sudoers, cause I modified it by myself; but I have downloaded both Openbox files from source ( https://openbox.org/dist/openbox/openbox-3.6.1.tar.xz ) and the the dpkg command still says are not the corrects (the reinstallation of the package do not add the files to this path).
Any way to get that two valid files? Thanks

See at: https://www.dwarmstrong.org/openbox/

Same result. Thanks.
